# Ubuntu 16.04 Imagemagick convert jpg webp

Tags: bash, 16.04, imagemagick, webp

I was wondering about the following;

I use the following command to find .jpg files in (sub)directorys and convert (mogrify) them to .webp files.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir mogrify -format webp {} \;
```

In this case: file.jpg becomes file.webp (and .jpg is kept).

**What I want is:**

Example: file.jpg becomes file.jpg.webp (and .jpg is kept).

1. How can I modify my code that it will set .jpg.webp?
2. Is there a code that checks if a file is already converted so it will pass, UNLESS the original .jpg file is newer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Your first question can be addressed easily enough:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -exec  convert '{}' -format webp '{}'.webp \;
```

This will:

1. Recursively find all .jpg files, as in your example
2. Convert each .jpg file to webp using `convert` rather than `mogrify`
3. Use the naming convention you were after: 'filename.jpg.webp'

Tested nicely on my system...

**References:**

- [ImageMagick: Batch Processing Examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_not)

Comment: Thanks for answering Q1. My result is this:

**'find . -iname '*.jpg' | parallel --eta convert '{}' -format webp '{}'.webp \;**